# Change font of UINavigationController title

Tags: ios, fonts, uinavigationcontroller, title

Can I change the font of my UINavigationController? --> **title**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The title view can be any view. So just create a UILabel or something else where you change the font and assign that new view to the title property of the navigation item.

Comment: That's a great idea, but I have a problem now,..

When I add my UILabel my controls (like AddButton) on the uinavigationcontroller isn't visible anymore,.. *hm*

Comment: I fixed it, by myself.. sorry a missunderstood ;)

Comment: if this fixed the problem, dont forget to accept the solution provided in the answer

Answer (score 74):

As of iOS 5 you can change the font via the appearance proxy.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

The following will set the title font for all UINavigationControllers.

```
  NSMutableDictionary *titleBarAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UINavigationBar appearance] titleTextAttributes]];
  [titleBarAttributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:16] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleBarAttributes];
```

To set the font for the back button, do this:

```
  NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
  [attributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:12] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
  [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To set the font for the large titles available in iOS 11+, do this:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    NSMutableDictionary *largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UINavigationBar appearance] largeTitleTextAttributes]];
    [largeTitleTextAttributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:32] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setLargeTitleTextAttributes:largeTitleTextAttributes];
}
```

Comment: iOS 7 deprecated the key: UITextAttributeFont (read, don't use this) and now uses the key: NSFontAttributeName instead. Works wonders and makes my app look a heck of a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: In each individual view controller you can also set the title text attributes on the instance of current navigation bar to customize the appearance there, like this code snippet:  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Bold" size:28], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

Answer (score 26):

for iOS8+ you can use:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:18.0f],
                                                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                   }];
```

Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: 18.0)!]
```

Comment: Thanks this gave me the right direction to implement a custom font with swift: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: 18.0)!]

Comment: Thanks, mate! Solved it.

Comment: Always sad when trying out first all above answers just to find out the bottom one is the most modern one \:

Answer (score 10):

An example:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [FontHelper fontFor:FontTargetForNavigationHeadings];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = self.navigationItem.title;
    // emboss in the same way as the native title
    [label setShadowColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -0.5)];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. If viewControllers in stack require different font for title, then `[UINavigationBar appearance]` can't do the job. A custom titleView is the only method.

Comment: its better to put this code in viewDidLoad, else every time the view comes up in hierarchy, titleView will be created and its unnecessary work on the system

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @morgancodes will set the font for all `UINavigationController` titles. I've updated it for Swift 4:

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Menlo", size: 14) as Any]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```